# How to redirect error output in Powershell Core?

Tags: powershell

I'm tryin to redirect any errors to null, but I can't seem to get it. Any help?

Here is my code: `$names | foreach-object{Copy-Item -Path C:\Users\$_\* -Destination C:\Users\$user\Desktop\${_}_removed -Recurse} | out-null`

Full error text:
[image]

Comment: Does `>$null` works?

Comment: No. It doesn't work. Doesn't matter though. The script still works, but the error is annoying.

Comment: please add the FULL text of your error msg. that will let folks know what kind of stream is involved & the source of the error ... which will allow suppressing it or redirecting it as needed.

Comment: Did it. There was too much error text and I couldn't add a picture, so it is a link instead.

Comment: You should always be able to copy and paste from a console to here (no such thing as "too much"); it's always better to do so **unless** the color of the text is of critical importance to the specific problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I commend to your attention the [Microsoft documentation on PowerShell redirection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7.1).

To redirect the error stream to null, you would apply `2>$null` to the cmdlet that's throwing the error. ***HOWEVER***...

Presumably, it is the `Copy-Item` cmdlet that is throwing the errors; if so, instead of trying to redirect-and-discard the error stream, you should suppress it entirely. This can be done by adding the parameter `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to the `Copy-Item` cmdlet:

```
$names | ForEach-Object { Copy-Item -Path C:\Users\$_\* -Destination C:\Users\$user\Desktop\${_}_removed -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue }
```

Comment: I would use `Ignore` instead of `SilentlyContinue` if you don't work with errors at all. If error handling is required then I would suggest to use `Stop` within a `try {..} catch {...}`  block to do it properly (alternatively with `trap {...}`). `SilentlyContinue` still writes the error stream to the automatic variable `$Error` which is just useless if you never handle it and therefore just produces overhead and consumes memory.

Comment: @pwnosh Right on, always looking for little things to further optimize PowerShell logic. I'm making a mental note on this tip for when not needing any error detail to test with `-Ignore` rather than `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`. I tend to have to use `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` so I'll likely be putting this to the test soon.

Comment: @pwnosh - Point taken; I'll have to admit that this was a failure of memory for me; I simply didn't remember that `-ea Ignore` was an option. Your comment about using `-ea Stop` within a `try...catch...` block for actually handling errors on your own is well-taken, and a technique that I use frequently - but didn't appear to be what the querent was interested in.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin That worked. I didn't realize that the -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue was inside the brackets. Thanks for the help!